# Django Upgrade from 1.1.1 to 1.5 or any other

Tags: python, django

I am working on a project using Django-1.1.1 which has become obsolete and is no more available for consumption. As a result, we're pondering to upgrade it to django's later version so that we can build on it. Here are some of the questions before us:

- What version of Django do you recommend we upgrade to?
- What are the Python compatibilities?
- Are there any hardware enhancements do I need to do for server?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would upgrade to the latest stable release (1.6.1). You can read through the release notes for each major version of Django here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/ . In particular, the "depreciated" section will give you an indication of the changes you will need to make to your codebase (which I'd imagine will be moderate to substantial). You won't need any hardware enhancements but you will need to upgrade python to >= 2.6.5. I would certainly recommend copying your project to a new server and working off a separate "upgrade" branch

Comment: Timmy: Why didn't you provide that as the answer? It looks good enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

> What version of Django do you recommend we upgrade to?

You should always upgrade to the latest official release, available from [this page](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) or downloadable from pypi with `pip install django`:

> If you’re just looking for a stable deployment target and don’t mind
>   waiting for the next release, you’ll want to stick with the latest
>   official release (which will always include detailed notes on any
>   changes you’ll need to make while upgrading).

For maximum stability and support, you should upgrade to and utilize the Long Term Support (LTS) version. 1.8 is the first LTS version of django; and is supported till April 2018.

> What are the Python compatibilities?

Any issues with compatibility (including the Python versions supported) are listed in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/). You should check the release notes for the major version first.

> Are there any hardware enhancements do I need to do for server?

This will depend on the volume of traffic on your application, and is really not something that will be controlled or influenced by the version of django or Python being used.